# What happened to the Visit Parent/Visit Meta links on the top left?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

There used to be Visit Parent / Visit Meta links in the top left corner but now it is replaced with a link to a generic list of StackExchange sites.  How can we easily get back and forth between meta and the parent site?

Comment: I now see the parent/meta link in the header on the right in between log out and about.  I guess it is not a bug but I liked it in the other location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the Meta/Parent links are located in the top menu bar:

[image]